# Image hover not showing

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a series of images that should show the background when hovered but don't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/w3rwf/

```
img:hover {
background:url("file:///F|/Desktop/testing%20new%20site/hehehe%20-%20Copy/img/hover.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-position: center; 
  -webkit-transition-duration: .05s; /* Safari */
transition-duration: .05s;  }
```

Comment: In your fiddle, `background-color; #000;` is an error – that should be a `:` instead between property name and value.

Comment: The code you have written is correct but in fiddle there is a syntax mistakes as @CBroe commented. So you should check on the background url and give correct image path.

Comment: Sorry! I guess I didn't copy paste correctly. I changed the fiddle. However, the problem is that sure the background shows up the image still appears above it. Can you give the background a priority to cover the image when hovered?

Comment: Ok let me modify the example so that you don't see the image.

Comment: Ok, just added a new jsfiddle for you in my answer. Feel free to vote it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this link: http://jsfiddle.net/S6aUy/4/

The issue was that you had the wrong syntax for background-color.

you had a typo here: `background-color; #000;`

Instead you should have typed `background-color: #000;`

Also I suggest you to use a IDE with a linting tool in order to spot those errors quickly.

**EDIT:** I added a new example to show you how to achieve what you were looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/J2M9P/

Comment: IDE with linting tools - overrated? Nah.. not really...

Comment: That is surely not an issue, but I wanted to point him out to be careful to the syntax.

Comment: I didn't mean to critique your answer. It was my way of saying "That sort of problem can be avoided if you use proper tools like an IDE with linting capabilities."

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with 2 day one with this: [Click and see the code](http://jsfiddle.net/S6aUy/7/).

or with div tag for the same and use the backgroung image.

```
<div class="imgbox"></div>

<style>
.imgbox{
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  background-image: image path;
  height:200px; width:200px;
}    

.imgbox:hover{
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  background-image: next image path;
  height:200px; width:200px;
}
</style>
```